# How to auto-stretch UI Controls using auto-layout

Tags: xcode, autolayout

I have got some buttons in my view and I want them to automatically resize based on the device on which they are running. Which constraints should I apply to them?

Answer (score 1):

To automatically resize button as per the screen size follow this steps

1 take the ratio of the width & height on the basis of the super view

2 the give them equal width & equal height constrains of button with respect to super view

3 then give ratio which you get in multiplier

4 build & Run.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the ones shown in the image. Considering that you have enable size-classes and working in wAny hAny

[image]

Comment: Thanks it's working with one button. What if I have many buttons in my view?

Comment: For complex configurations, you have to apply constraints according to how your buttons are displaying in your view. Can you post a screenshot of the view.